# Return to top of UINavigationController stack when clicking a tab?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` interface with 4 tabs. Each tab has a `UINavigationController`. How would I return to the topmost `UIViewController` in each `UINavigationController` whenever a tab bar button is pressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[-popToRootViewControllerAnimated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)